# How can I see my LAN when connected to a VPN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, lan

At home I use a VPN and to share it with other devices I use the computer which connects to the VPN as access point for a second LAN, but I don't want all the traffic be routed through the VPN: I want to be able to choose whether to use plain internet or the VPN, so I have the following setting:

- My router is connected to my ISP and, on the local side, creates a LAN on the private addresses 10.10.10.* and it is the gateway with address 10.10.10.10 for the LAN
- My pc (which runs ubuntu and has local address 10.10.10.100) is connected to the router via wifi and it is connected to my VPN provider
- The same pc has a wifi dongle which is configured to be the access point for another LAN on the addresses 192.168.23.* (and the pc is the gateway for this LAN with address 192.168.23.1)

This way I have two LANs: one which connects directly to the internet (10.10.10.* ) and another which connects through the VPN (192.168.23.* ).

Also, I have another PC which is a DLNA server for the 10.10.10.* LAN and a smarttv which connects to the VPN.

Summing up:

- 10.10.10.10: main router
- 10.10.10.23: pc1 with a DLNA server
- 10.10.10.100: wlan0 on pc2, connected to VPN
- 192.168.23.1: wlan1 on pc2
- 192.168.23.10: smarttv

To manage the traffic on pc2 I use this rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.23.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and the routing rules are

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.175.1.5      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
10.175.1.1      10.175.1.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.175.1.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
h88-150-252-230 10.10.10.10     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.23.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
```

Everything works fine.

Namely, from my smarttv (and any other device connected on the 192.168.23.*) I see the internet through the VPN whereas devices connected to the router get plain access to the internet.

The problem is that the tv doesn't see the DLNA server and the question is: is it possible to set it up in such a way that the tv can reach the DLNA server?

Comment: You need to make routing to the10.10.10.1 from 192.168.23.1 in your routing configuration on router

Comment: How  do I do this? I am not practical in defining routes.

Comment: What is your router model ?

Comment: It is a Netgear DGN 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a static route to the configuration. Select Advanced > Static Route

The Destination IP Address and IP Subnet Mask fields specify that this static route applies to all `10.10.10.0` subnet mask `255.255.255.0` addresses.

The Gateway IP Address field specifies that all traffic for these addresses are to be forwarded to the LAN at `192.168.23.1`.

The value in the Metric field represents the ***number of routers***  your network and
the destination.

> This should 0 from your routing table

.

The Private check box is selected only as a precautionary security measure in case RIP is activated

Please read [this](http://www.netcheif.com/downloads/NETGEAR_DGN1000-UM.pdf) documentation in Configure Static Routes Section to add static route.
Hope this help you out.

Comment: I tried Dest IP Addr `10.10.10.0`, mask `255.255.255.0`, Gateway IP `192.168.23.1`, Metric `2`, but when I apply it I get an "Unknown error" box

Comment: Please try to change Metric = 0, same as your routing table...
if error still occured, please tell me.

Comment: With Metric=0 I get an error which says that metric should be in the interval 2-15

Comment: hmm.. so, the metric should 2-15 ? have you tried to change the metric and have you tried to changed the Destination 10.10.10.0 and gateway * ?

Comment: I have tried with many different settings but when the route is accepted, it has not the desired effect. Maybe the problem lies in the iptables on pc2 ?!?

Comment: Can you provide your IPtables on PC1 and PC2 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22623/discussion-between-brad-and-eko-junaidi-salam).

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to insert messages in the chat: the system keep saying that I need to be logged in. Maybe I have not enough reputation

Comment: on both computers, chains INPUT/FORWARD/OUTPUT are empty, with policy ACCEPT. On pc2, `Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.23.0/24      anywhere      `

Comment: What's the configuration you create in static route in your previous comment but it has not desired effect ?

Comment: Settings Dest IP Addr 192.168.23.0, mask 255.255.255.0, Gateway IP 10.10.10.100, Metric 2 are accepted

Comment: Try this 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gtw 192.168.23.1 metric 2, hope the tv can reach the DLNA server.

Comment: With that I get "Unknow error". I am starting to think the router firmware is buggy (yet, it is up to date)

Comment: "Unknow Error" again ?
Not specific enough about the error information it self.

Comment: Please try Dest IP Addr 10.10.10.0, mask 255.255.255.0, Gateway IP 192.168.23.0, Metric 2, hope this save you

Comment: At the end, I discovered that the settings Dest IP Addr `192.168.23.0`, mask `255.255.255.0`, Gateway IP `10.10.10.100`, Metric `2` do the job: the two subnets see each other (at least, with VPN turned off) so I can ssh from one pc in a subnet to another in the other one. Nonetheless, I discovered also that I can't see the DLNA server because UPNP works only in the same subnet: to have it work accross subnets I need a UPNP proxy. But even using one, in my case I am not lucky, since I use minidlna which, I discovered, has a bug preventing him to work accross subnets. Thanks for your help.